# how to make two objects spin individual to each other using HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a newbie to html canvas. I'm trying to spin two wheel looking figures to rotate to form like a base for a car (for example) However, the following code rotates the 2nd wheel around the first wheel (while this is spinning in the centre).

```
function wheel(rot,angle) {

    c.save();
    c.beginPath();
    this.rot = rot;
    for(var i =0; i<2*Math.PI; i = i + 0.01) {
        var x = 50 * Math.cos(6 * i) * Math.cos(i);
        var y = 50 * Math.cos(6 * i) * Math.sin(i);

        c.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    if(this.rot===1) {
        c.fill();
    }else{
        c.stroke();
    }
}

var slider1 = document.getElementById('slider1');
var slider2 = document.getElementById('slider2');
slider2.value =1;
slider1.value = 1;


function draw() {

    c.clearRect(-450, -450, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    c.save();
    c.rotate(slider2.value);

    wheel(1);

    c.restore();
    c.save();
    c.translate(200, 200);

    wheel(2);

    c.restore();
    c.restore();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


c.save();

c.translate(400, 200);

draw();
```

I think my mistake lies in the placement of c.save() and c.restore() but 
I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is an unbalanced `c.save()` call in your `wheel` function. Your other uses of `save` and `restore` are fine, but in general these calls need to be balanced (also accounting for nested function calls, like your `wheel` function). This is akin to balancing parenthesis in a math equation or balancing brackets in blocks of code.

If you remove all code except for `save` and `restore` calls, it's easy to see what is going wrong. Keeping a mental counter, start at zero and add 1 for each `save` call, and subtract 1 for each `restore` call. At the end, you should end up back at zero.

```
function wheel(rot,angle) {
    c.save();
}

function draw() {
    // counter = 0
    c.save();
    // counter = 1

    wheel(1); // contains save() call
    // counter = 2

    c.restore();
    // counter = 1
    c.save();
    // counter = 2

    wheel(2); // contains save() call
    // counter = 3

    c.restore();
    // counter = 2;
    c.restore();
    // counter = 1;
}
```

We're at the end of the draw() function and our counter equals 1. Something is unbalanced, and quick analysis reveals the wheel() function is the culprit, with its unmatched save() call.

The `wheel` function isn't mutating the canvas state, so it doesn't really need to use save and restore. If you remove the save() call from the wheel function, things are almost balanced. The last change is removing the redundant restore() call at the end of draw().

Below is a snippet you can run that includes these changes, and a few others to enable independent rotation of the two wheels.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var slider1 = document.getElementById('slider1');
var slider2 = document.getElementById('slider2');

function wheel(rot,angle) {
    c.beginPath();
    this.rot = rot;
    for(var i =0; i<2*Math.PI; i = i + 0.01) {
        var x = 50 * Math.cos(6 * i) * Math.cos(i);
        var y = 50 * Math.cos(6 * i) * Math.sin(i);

        c.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    if(this.rot===1) {
        c.fill();
    }else{
        c.stroke();
    }
}


function draw() {

    c.clearRect(-100, -100, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    c.save();
    c.rotate(slider1.value);

    wheel(1);

    c.restore();
    c.save();
    c.translate(200, 0);
    c.rotate(slider2.value);

    wheel(2);

    c.restore();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


c.save();

c.translate(100, 100);

draw();
```

```html
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="6.28" step="0.01" />
<input id="slider2" type="range" min="0" max="6.28" step="0.01" />
<canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This solution was very helpful. However, any thoughts as to why both the wheels don't rotate (animation) on their own (I am calling the requestAnimationFrame under this)?

Comment: @SaiRohit They don't spin continuously because each frame the rotation is being set to the current slider's value. So, they only rotate when you change the slider. If you want continuous animation, you'll want to create a variable to store the current rotation, and change the variable on each frame. Then rotate the wheel(s) based on that variable. Make sense?

Comment: I have added an update function which updates two variables and sends them as args to the draw function. I'm calling the update function in an other function called animate which has the requestAnimationFrame. However, both the wheels disappear from the canvas page. Your answer makes sense but I'm not sure of this unusual behaviour. thanks!

Comment: @SaiRohit Sounds like you're on the right track, but maybe you didn't call `animate` initially to get things started? Just a guess. This is a slightly different question, so I created a working example on CodePen, have a look: https://codepen.io/MillerTime/pen/bcce73b14bec369b8be4064899a04279?editors=1010

If this is helpful, can you please mark this answer as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: My bad! I accidentally commented out the call to the function! thanks for the answer!